# Pdf of the product of an exponential r.v. and a beta r.v.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ are 2 independent random variables, where $X$ has an exponential distribution with parameter $1$ and $Y$ is $\beta(a,b)$ distributed.

What is the Pdf of $W=XY$ ?

Thanks !

Comment: The PDf and the CDF of $W$ can be expressed in terms of confluent hypergeometric functions of the second kind, is this the kind of information you are after?

Comment: I need the expression of Pdf and it doesn't matter if it contains a hypergeometric function or not. (Plz I need the main steps of the calculation)

Comment: The PDF **will** contain a hypergeometric function, this is not a choice... OK, since you are asking for a detailed proof, you have to show first what you did to solve this question and why your approach failed.

Comment: I tried this [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Derivation_for_independent_random_variables), but it's hard to compute the integral

Comment: Pdf= $(B(a,b))^{-1} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}  \frac{w^{a-1}}{x^{a-1}} (1-\frac{w}{x})^{b-1}  \frac{1}{x} dx = \\
  w^{a-1} (B(a,b))^{-1} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}  \frac{1}{x^{a+b-1}} (x-w)^{b-1}   dx $

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be the p.d.f. of $X$ (exponential distribution) and let $g$ be the p.d.f. of $Y$ (beta distribution).  The c.d.f. of $W=XY$ is then:
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{w/y} f(x)g(y) \, dx \, dy$$

The bounds of integration come from the support of $X$ and $Y$ (i.e. X has a exponential distribution so $x \ge 0$, and $Y$ has a beta distribution so $0 \le y \le 1$).

Comment: I tried this formula but It's hard to solve the integral! plz could you give me the detailed calculation.

Comment: I have no idea how to compute the integral, or if it even has a closed form.  If you only need the pdf, you could try differentiating with respect to $w$ and then attempting the integration.